# iPad App Distribution

Tags: ipad

I am developing a native iPad app that connects to our servers and returns specific information. This app is targeting external companies.  The overall app has a client and a server.  The client is the iPad app and the server component is what will be installed.
We do have licensing framework in place on the server component.

I understand that there are 3 different forms of app deployment.  I am looking for ideas for implementing a strategy where an app can be distributed via appStore BUT will work ONLY for a certain specified users.

So for example , If Charlie from Company A has the server component installed on his server AND downloads the iPad app on his iPad, this should work. However, if Marie downloads an this app from appstore, it should not do anything.  Any ideas / options / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are interested in B2B distribution via the AppStore. Check out [this page](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) for more information.

Once you land on that page you can find the B2B section that states

> Custom B2B apps are built just for you by third-party developers and business partners to address a specific business process, integrate with a unique back-office environment, or deliver a custom interface for your users. Using the Volume Purchase Program, you can securely and privately purchase custom B2B apps for iPhone and iPad that make your business even more effective.
>
> If you are a developer who is enrolled in the iOS Developer program you can create custom B2B apps for sale to your customers enrolled in the Volume Purchase Program.

[Learn more about developing custom B2B apps](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/volume/) (requires developer login)

Depending on the route you take you may need to create individual build targets for each customer with that is setup to point to the URL of their installed server.

Otherwise you could have a generic app that hits a centralized login server, based on the user credentials it forwards the app to the appropriate server.

Answer (score -2):

Have an account system for the servers.